# scope an eventhandler by reference in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to call a class function from within a class, which I previously attached to a button-object that resides within the class (the following code works but the scope in callMyClassFunction is on button and I want it to be the Carousel):

```
//Examplecode 1
Carousel.prototype.addEventListeners = function(){
    this.button.on('click', this.callMyClassFunction);
}

Carousel.prototype.callMyClassFunction = function(){
    console.log(this);
}
```

If I bind the function like that it works (the scope of this is the class instance):

```
//Examplecode 2
Carousel.prototype.addEventListeners = function(){
    this.button.on('click', function(){
        this.callMyClassFunction()
    }).bind(this);
}
```

But I'd rather want to add the click-eventlistener with a reference (like in Examplecode 1) since I want to call removeListener in yet another function:

```
//Examplecode 3
Carousel.prototype.removeEventListeners = function(condition){
    if(condition){
        this.button.removeListener('click', this.callMyClassFunction);
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the bound listener on your instance:

```
functin Carousel(…) {
    …
    this.callMyClassFunction = this.callMyClassFunction.bind(this);
}
Carousel.prototype.callMyClassFunction = function(){
    console.log(this);
};
Carousel.prototype.addEventListeners = function(){
    this.button.on('click', this.callMyClassFunction);
};
Carousel.prototype.removeEventListeners = function(…){
    …
    this.button.removeListener('click', this.callMyClassFunction);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind` rather more simply:

```
Carousel.prototype.addEventListeners = function(){
    this.button.on('click', this.callMyClassFunction.bind(this));
};
```

I'm not sure what `bind` you were using in your example (you were calling it on the return value of the `on` function), but the above uses `Function#bind`, which is a part of JavaScript itself (as of ES5; it's easy to shim/polyfill for older browsers). `Function#bind` returns a new function that, when called, calls the original function with `this` set to the first argument you give `bind`. So in the above, a click will call the function returned by `bind`, which will call `callMyClassFunction` with `this` set to the correct value.

If you need to use `removeListener` later and it requires the **same** function be passed into it, you'll have to remember the function, like this:

```
Carousel.prototype.addEventListeners = function(){
    if (!this.boundCallMyClassFunction) {
        this.boundCallMyClassFunction = this.callMyClassFunction.bind(this);
    }
    this.button.on('click', this.boundCallMyClassFunction);
};

Carousel.prototype.removeEventListeners = function(condition){
    if(condition && this.boundCallMyClassFunction){
        this.button.removeListener('click', this.boundCallMyClassFunction);
    }
};
```

You can't just pass it the result of calling `bind` again, as that would be a different function.

But check the documentation of whatever's providing the `on` and `removeListener` functions you're calling above, it may provide a simpler way to do that (jQuery does, but it doesn't look like you're using jQuery there).

Comment: thanks a lot, this works fine. But as for the removing of the listener I prefer Bergi's method.

Comment: Yup, that works too, provided you don't ever need that method unbound (which you frequently don't).